# What does n times a generator of a cyclic group mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, cyclic-groups, fundamental-groups

[image]

It seems to be saying that, for some integer *deg(f)* it sends the generator *i* to *deg(f)* times the generator, but I can only see it making sense if it sends it to the generator^*deg(f)*

What does it mean here to send *i* to *deg(f)i* ?

Comment: If a group is abelian then the operation is often written additively.

Comment: Does that mean that in this case ni = i^n ?

Comment: It means that what you would write as $i^n$ if you were using multiplicative notation you write instead as $ni$ if you are using additive notation. It certainly doesn't mean $ni=i^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the group is abelian, you write we denote the group operation by $+$ and the $n$ fold application of the operation with multiplication. In particular, we have $\langle \alpha\rangle=\mathbb Z= \pi_1(S_1,1)$ so that every element can be written as $\alpha+\dots +\alpha=n\cdot \alpha$.